# Add --insecure-registry argument to docker daemon on centos 6

Tags: docker

trying to connect the docker daemon on centos 6.6 (non systemd) to our private registry without a cert.  [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/) says to edit /etc/default/docker to add insecure-registry argument and restart the service, but this has no effect:

```
$ ps -ef | grep docker
tiiuser  19986 19447  0 10:25 pts/1    00:00:00 grep docker
root     31877     1  0 Apr04 ?        00:00:26 /usr/bin/docker
```

How can I add the --insecure-registry argument to the docker daemon in centos 6?

Comment: What version of `docker` are you running?

Answer (score 5):

add the following to:

```
 vi /etc/sysconfig/docker

 other_args="--insecure-registry <your private registry:port>"
```

restart the service:

```
 service docker restart
```

verify the argument was added:

```
$ ps -ef | grep docker
tiiuser  19986 19447  0 10:25 pts/1    00:00:00 grep docker
root     31877     1  0 Apr04 ?        00:00:26 /usr/bin/docker -d --  <your private registry url)
```

To automate this as part of a script:

```
echo "other_args=\"--insecure-registry <your private registry url>\"" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysconfig/docker
```